# drakma:http-request crashes during https request while using burp as a proxy

Tags: common-lisp, drakma, burp

I want to study some outgoing traffic of drakma by using the burp-suites as a automatic proxy.

But when making https request drakma signals (more precisely cl+ssl drakma uses) crashes:

```
(drakma:http-request "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
             :proxy '("127.0.0.1" 8080))
```

=>

```
A failure in the SSL library occurred on handle #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00677EE0) (return code: 1). SSL error queue:
error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error

   [Condition of type CL+SSL::SSL-ERROR-SSL]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME interactive evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [REMOVE-FD-HANDLER] Remove #<SB-IMPL::HANDLER INPUT on descriptor 6: #<CLOSURE (LABELS SWANK-BACKEND::RUN :IN SWANK-BACKEND:ADD-FD-HANDLER) {100314533B}>>
 3: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

Backtrace:
  0: (CL+SSL::SSL-SIGNAL-ERROR #.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X00677EE0) #<FUNCTION CL+SSL::SSL-CONNECT> 1 -1)
  1: (CL+SSL:MAKE-SSL-CLIENT-STREAM #<unavailable lambda list>)
  2: (DRAKMA:HTTP-REQUEST #<PURI:URI https://www.stackoverflow.com/> :PROXY ("127.0.0.1" 8080))
```

I would like to know what this error means (as i was not able to find a propper documentation of cl+ssl) and how to fix/prevent this from happening?

Comment: well burpsuite is (as far as I know) designed for performing man-in-the-middle attacks, therefore the proxy should "speak" https

Comment: To me, this looks as if it is a problem local to your machine.  Maybe something with your SSL installation is not quite right?  I have downloaded Burp Suite, started it, started the drakma:http-request command that you've shown and things work just fine.

(This is with OSX 10.8.2, SBCL 1.1)

Comment: @wvxvw yes it does work if the traffic is not encrypted

Comment: @hans23 that is quite fascinating. I am using Ubuntu 12.10 SBCL 1.1